# How get snapshot of my canvas

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, ajax

I develop small application using javascript, using this I can draw on the canvas.I want to know, **How get snapshot of my canvas** and send it another one,

using javascript or any other server side language.
please help me.thanks.

Comment: since when javascript become server side language? :)

Comment: @Syom - He said *or*, but there are many server-side implementations of JS :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Server-side_JavaScript_solutions

Answer (score 4):

You can get a PNG image of the canvas as a data URL via the **[toDataURL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl)** method:

```
canvas.toDataURL(); // => data:...
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this tutorial, it shows how to take a snapshot of your canvas and send it to your server using AJAX.

[Send Canvas Content to Server](http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2011/06/send-canvas-content-to-server/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) to save an HTML 5 canvas to file for download purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:

```
window.location.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
```

This causes the browser's location to change to a data-url containing a PNG of the canvas contents that the browser will then prompt to save (changing the mime-type forces that, otherwise the browser will just display the PNG.)

Comment: Nice tip. Though note that this doesn't work for iOS devices (cannot download file error) but if you leave the mime-type as is the user can save the resulting image that loads (a two-step process instead of one).